# How to use filter to search in multiple key values of objects in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, filtering, vuejs2

I have an array of wines containing objects with data for each wine:

```
var wines = [
  { _id: '59a740b8aa06e549918b1fda',
    wineryName: 'Some Winery',
    wineName: 'Pinot Noir',
    wineColor: 'Red',
    imageLink: '/img/FortBerensPN.png' },
  { _id: '59a7410aaa06e549918b1fdb',
    wineryName: 'Some Winery',
    wineName: 'Pinot Gris',
    wineColor: 'White',
    imageLink: '/img/FortBerensPG.png' },
  { _id: '59a74125aa06e549918b1fdc',
    wineryName: 'Some Winery',
    wineName: 'Rose',
    wineColor: 'Rose',
    imageLink: '/img/FortBerensRose.png' },
  { _id: '59a74159aa06e549918b1fdd',
    wineryName: 'Some other Winery',
    wineName: 'Rose',
    wineColor: 'Rose',
    imageLink: '/img/FortBerensRose.png' },
  { _id: '59a7417aaa06e549918b1fde',
    wineryName: 'Some other Winery',
    wineName: 'Pinot Gris',
    wineColor: 'White',
    imageLink: '/img/FortBerensPG.png' },
  { _id: '59a8721f4fd43b676a1f5f0d',
    wineryName: 'Some other Winery',
    wineName: 'Pinot Gris',
    wineColor: 'White',
    imageLink: '/img/FortBerensPG.png' },
  { _id: '59a872244fd43b676a1f5f0e',
    wineryName: 'Winery 3',
    wineName: 'Pinot Noir',
    wineColor: 'Red',
    imageLink: '/img/FortBerensPN.png' } ]
```

I can figure out how to search -- case insensitive -- for a wine object, while specifying which key of the object to search in, like this:

```
var search = 'Noir'

filteredWines = function () {
  return wines.filter(function(wine){
    return (wine.wineName.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase())>=0;
  });
};
```

Returns:

```
[ { _id: '59a740b8aa06e549918b1fda',
    wineryName: 'Some Winery',
    wineName: 'Pinot Noir',
    wineColor: 'Red',
    imageLink: '/img/FortBerensPN.png' },
  { _id: '59a872244fd43b676a1f5f0e',
    wineryName: 'Winery 3',
    wineName: 'Pinot Noir',
    wineColor: 'Red',
    imageLink: '/img/FortBerensPN.png' } ]
```

However, if `var search = 'Winery 3'` or `var search = 'red'` then it will obviously return no results, as it's looking in the value of `wineName` of each object in the array.

So is there a way to use filter (or another method?) to search through all key values, or even better, multiple specified key values and return an array of the matching objects?

Something like:

```
filteredWines = function () {
  return wines.filter(function(wine){
    return ((wine.wineName.toLowerCase() && wine.wineName.toLowerCase() 
          && wine.wineName.toLowerCase()).indexOf(search.toLowerCase())>=0;
  });
};
```

Or am I completely barking up the wrong tree?

PS. I'm using Vue.js 2 so if there's a better way inside vue then I'm all ears!

Comment: Should each property be searched for one value? Or are you specifying a different search value for each property?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, but I think simply using an OR operator would work? You could clean up this part by creating a function `(wine.wineName.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase())>=0`. Or, you could use a regex.

Comment: BTW, take your pick from whatever filter method people end up posting, but a [computed property](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) would be the ideal way to use it in Vue.

Comment: @Bert I was stuffing this in a computed property and returning the results :) Thanks for making that clear for others though!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could have a more generic function that will scan *all* the properties for the string. Loop through all property values with `Object.values()` and use `some` to bail out as soon as you have a match:

```
filteredWines = function (search) {
    var lowSearch = search.toLowerCase();
    return wines.filter(wine =>
        Object.values(wine).some(val => 
            String(val).toLowerCase().includes(lowSearch) 
        )
    );
}
```

If you prefer to pass specific keys to search in:

```
filteredWines = function (search, keys) {
    var lowSearch = search.toLowerCase();
    return wines.filter(wine =>
        keys.some(key => 
            String(wine[key]).toLowerCase().includes(lowSearch) 
        )
    );
}
```

Call as

```
filteredWines('Winery 3', ['wineryName', 'wineName']);
```

Comment: This is awesome thank you! And thanks again @Bert for beautifully vuetifying it for me :)

Comment: saved much time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can also be done this way:

```
    this.wines = this.wines.filter((item) => {
                return (item.wineryName.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
                item.wineName.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
                item.wineColor.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
            })
```

Answer (score 1):

Used the solution from "trincot" and changed it for my angular5 application to this:

```
filter(search, list): Observable<IFilteredList> {
  return list.filter(item => {
    return Object.values(item).some(val =>
      String(val).includes(search)
    );
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter works. Oops, I read the question a bit more closely. Filter still works but you have to filter the values, too.

```js
let wines = [
    {
        _id: '59a740b8aa06e549918b1fda',
        wineryName: 'Some Winery',
        wineName: 'Pinot Noir',
        wineColor: 'Red',
        imageLink: '/img/FortBerensPN.png'
    },
    {
        _id: '59a7410aaa06e549918b1fdb',
        wineryName: 'Some Winery',
        wineName: 'Pinot Gris',
        wineColor: 'White',
        imageLink: '/img/FortBerensPG.png'
    },
    {
        _id: '59a74125aa06e549918b1fdc',
        wineryName: 'Some Winery',
        wineName: 'Rose',
        wineColor: 'Rose',
        imageLink: '/img/FortBerensRose.png'
    },
    {
        _id: '59a74159aa06e549918b1fdd',
        wineryName: 'Some other Winery',
        wineName: 'Rose',
        wineColor: 'Rose',
        imageLink: '/img/FortBerensRose.png'
    },
    {
        _id: '59a7417aaa06e549918b1fde',
        wineryName: 'Some other Winery',
        wineName: 'Pinot Gris',
        wineColor: 'White',
        imageLink: '/img/FortBerensPG.png'
    },
    {
        _id: '59a8721f4fd43b676a1f5f0d',
        wineryName: 'Some other Winery',
        wineName: 'Pinot Gris',
        wineColor: 'White',
        imageLink: '/img/FortBerensPG.png'
    },
    {
        _id: '59a872244fd43b676a1f5f0e',
        wineryName: 'Winery 3',
        wineName: 'Pinot Noir',
        wineColor: 'Red',
        imageLink: '/img/FortBerensPN.png'
    }
];

let search = (val) => wines.filter(w => Object.values(w).filter(v => v.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) !== -1).length > 0);

console.log(search('some'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I also would recommend trying a more general approach:

```
function getMatchingWhine(keys, searchTerm, wines) {

  function extractTextFromKeys(keys, object) {
    let text = '';
    keys.forEach(key => {
        text += ' ' + object[key];
    });
    return text.toLowerCase();
  }

  return wines.filter(wine => {
    const relevantText = extractTextFromKeys(keys, wine);
    return relevantText.includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase());
  });
}
```